# Jquery checked or display

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with this code, I want do delete all `testdiv` with `style="display:none"` and all fields that aren't checked.

But with this code it deletes all `testdiv`.

```
$("#post_form").submit(function() {
    if ($('div[id^="testdiv_"]').not(":checked") || $('div[id^="testdiv_"]').css("display", "none")) {
        $('div[id^="testdiv_"]').remove();
        alert('OK');
    }
    else {
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is `testdiv`?  What are you trying to remove?  What is your condition?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/8QM8n/](http://jsfiddle.net/8QM8n/)
That's what i want. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`$('div[id^="testdiv_"]').css("display", "none")` sets all divs with an id beginning "testdiv_" to a display of none, which `$('div[id^="testdiv_"]').remove();` then conveniently removes.

To check the css, instead of set the css, use `$('div[id^="testdiv_"]').css("display") === "none"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div[id^="testdiv_"]').css("display", "none")
```

This sets all `$('div[id^="testdiv_"]')` to be hidden.

Try `$('div[id^="testdiv_"]:hidden')`.

Also,

```
$('div[id^="testdiv_"]').remove();
```

This deletes all `$('div[id^="testdiv_"]')`.  Try something like this instead:

```
$('div[id^="testdiv_"]:hidden,div[id^="testdiv_"]:not(:checked)').remove();
```

Comment: Ok I've tested it but it does not work. Here you can view it.
[http://jsfiddle.net/8QM8n/](http://jsfiddle.net/8QM8n/)

Answer (score 0):

The selector `$('div[id^="testdiv_"]')` selects all elements that match. Your code does the following:

```
For each element that matches($('div[id^="testdiv_"]').not(":checked") || $('div[id^="testdiv_"]').css("display", "none"))
    Remove all elements that match $('div[id^="testdiv_"]')
```

You probably want to use jQuery's .each: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/C